# Sprite Game Kit weird Scale/Edges/Size in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am a beginner to iOS app coding but not to coding in general. I am following a tutorial for a sprite game kit app and I am having some trouble with the sizing of stuff.  It came time to put in edges so the balls can bounce off of them.  I noticed that the edges seemed to be off the screen, the balls would leave the screen then bounce back.

So I had xcode output the width/height, it said 320x568.  I also change the scale mode by setting scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit; and you can see the boundaries look like a square:

[image]

If I put the scaling back to normal by scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill; It shows the screen like this:

[image]

but the balls still go off the screen.

By the way, I believe I am setting the edge nodes correctly to be on the left and right edge so I don't think that is the issue.

```
// Add edges
SKNode *leftEdge = [[SKNode alloc] init];
leftEdge.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) toPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.size.height)];
leftEdge.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[self addChild:leftEdge];

SKNode *rightEdge = [[SKNode alloc] init];
rightEdge.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) toPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.size.height)];
rightEdge.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width, 0);
[self addChild:rightEdge];
```

Comment: Did you try setting scene.scaleMode to SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill?

Comment: Yeah I did and that was the normal setting.  But the edges are still way off the screen.

Comment: Two things 1) change self.size to view.frame.size and 2) change the scaleMode back to SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill. You can also set skView.showsPhysics = YES; in your view controller to see an outline of the physics bodies in the scene.

Comment: Still though, my 0,0 point is far off the screen.  Not really sure :/  skView.showsPhysics = YES; is very helpful though, thanks.

Comment: I fixed the issue.

In the tutorial I am following, his view controller had the following

// Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene *scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

And in the version of Xcode that I have it had the following.

// Create and configure the scene.
    GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;


So I changed it to the first piece of code I posted and it worked.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In your GameScene file (or whatever you may have called the SKScene file), add this method to the start of `didMoveToView`:

`self.size = self.view.frame.size;`

What is happening is that your game thinks the screen is running a different size. You need to change self.size to the actual size of the frame you are working with. The above method works with `SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill`, but I have not yet tested it with the other modes. Good luck!